# How to only load n number of a relationship in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

I am looking to fetch a list of companies and some but not all of their job listings. For instance on the "companies in Denver" page I'd like to show a company and the most recent jobs that are in Denver. I use tags to specify where a jobs location is, but could alternatively do a ilike on the `job_listings.location` field.

I'm using Laravel 8 with Postgresql and have a query to get all the job listings that match the given tag:

```php
Company::whereIn('id', $companiesHiringInLocation->slice(0,15))
                ->with([
                    'jobListings' => function($query) use ($tag){
                        $query->withTagId($tag->id);
                    },
                    'jobListings.tags'
                ])
                ->get();
```

This works but some companies have thousands of job listings and I only need three job listings. This is how I'm rendering the list on the frontend currently:

```php
@foreach($companies as $company)
    @foreach($company->jobListings as $index => $jobListing)
        @if($index > 2) @break @endif
        <div>{{ $jobListing->title }}</div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Is there a way I can modify or write a separate query to only get three job listings for each company? There will only be 10-15 companies on the list.

As an example, AngelList renders this on their page here where company may have many jobs but they only show a few:

[image]

I'm looking to grab the companies and three of their most recent (or any three really) job listings instead of querying for all of them. Is there a way to do this better with Eloquent or raw SQL?

Comment: I think you can use "limi" or"take"... Insert one more line like $query->take(5);

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `take()` method, for example:

```
$compaines = Company::with
(['jobs'=>function($q) {
$q->take(3);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Doing the get on the relationship query gets all related job listings. Without the get it only gets three total